# How to use the event ng-change directive in input text only when the length of the changed value is equal to x?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a beginner in Angular and I try to solve this problem: I've an `<input/>` field:

```
<input 
  ng-model="codebare" 
  ng-change="addSale(codebare)" 
  name="keyWord"
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Product name or barcode value" 
  autofocus />
```

and as you may see it, I want to fetch the input value (`ng-model="codebare"`) any time it change. My problem is that this code is working only when the very first char has fill the field and as I'm using a barcode scanner, I want to get the full value (`3876666667677777287`) instead of the first char (`3`). Is there a simple way to do that ? I think on some directive like `ng-change-options="length"` but couldn't find it. following is my `addSale()` function:

```
$scope.addSale = function(codebare) {
    alert(codebare);
    var item = $scope.codebare;
    alert(item);
    $scope.orderedItemCnt = 1;
    var foodItem = {
        orderedItemCnt: 1,
        totalPrice: item.price,
        itemId: item.id, 
        id: $scope.itemsCnt,
        item: item
    };
}
```

Comment: try use $watch instead? like `scope.$watch('codebare',$scope.addSale)`

Comment: As I read about $watch it 's for the model therefore the directive ng-change is the one that will give data to $watch so ...I try this (of course it does not work): $scope.addSale = function(codebare) {
          $scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.data.codebare },
              function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  alert(newValue);
              }
             );
          ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a barcode scanner, I would add a ng-model-option of debounce so the model is not updated until the entire code has had time to be input fully.

I have created a sample below you can try.

```js
angular.module('optionsExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  var data = {
    1264274554897965: { id: "AGDFT144", price: 10.50 },
    3124142142123532: { id: "AGFHH156", price: 2.15 },
    6588969543172554: { id: "BNHKL102", price: 101.60 }
  };
    $scope.barcode = 6588969543172554;
  $scope.$watch("barcode", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue)
      addSale(newValue);
  });
  
  function addSale(barcode) {
    var item = data[barcode];
    var foodItem = {
        orderedItemCnt: 1,
        totalPrice: item.price,
        itemId: item.id,
    };
    console.log(foodItem);
  }
      
  

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="optionsExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="itemForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="barcode"
             ng-model="barcode"
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" />
    </label>
    <br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="barcode"></span></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow dude, [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) @Saint-CyrMAPOUKA. I'll delete my answer since you have it all figured out

Comment: I've fixed it can already then please can you remove the above comment ?

Comment: I now would like to edit the quantity of every item (not just use the plus / minus button ) but after defining an input of text like <input type="text" ng-model="quantityEdited"/> within the loops (ng-repeated), I couldn't get the value $scope.quantityEdited within the controller in order to update this particular item totalPrice and the whole sale price any help please scniro .... I appologize for lot of quation